# Form Field within Shape

Tags: html, css, forms, user-experience

I'm working to make a form more user-friendly. One of the easier ways I've seen is put the form field within the shape like so

[image: Concept of Design]

Outside of using a `table`, I have not come up with decent way to layout/code this concept. The problem with tables is that they do not support the curvature of certain shapes and are not responsive without distorting the shape. The images are SVGs paths so I'm curious if it possible to add a form field to a path?

For now, the only thing I could come up with was labeling each side (such as A,B,C, etc) and then having form fields separate that correlate.